# Typescript: Passing in interface with lambda expression

Tags: javascript, typescript, lambda

I'm attempting to pass in an interface into a method (forEachEntity) that takes a Consumer as its parameter.

**The interface:**

```
export interface Consumer<T> {
    accept(t: T): void;
}
```

**The method being called:**

```
cell.forEachEntity = (consumer: Consumer<E>): Consumer<E> => {
    return null;
}
```

This call does not throw an error, but I can't figure out what to make it return. I've looked through a lot of material on lambda expressions in typescript but have yet to figure it out.

Comment: make it return what? there is no call being done in your code..

Comment: It says it must return something, when I don't have the return statement there

Comment: The second `Consumer<E>` is the return type. Colon after function header is the syntax for defining return types in TypeScript, even in lambda expressions.

Comment: what I see is that you are defining a function that takes a consumer and returns a consumer.. it's not clear what you are trying to achieve..

Comment: Oh, I guess I wasn't doing it correctly then. In my first statement I said I'm trying to pass in a consumer into the forEachEntity function.

Comment: if you don't want to return just remove the part after the : in the forEachEntity method definition.

Answer (score 0):

Do something with the consumer (or make a new one, etc...).

```
cell.forEachEntity = (consumer: Consumer<E>): Consumer<E> => {
    consumer.accountBalance += 100;
    return consumer;
    //or whatever your app is supposed to be doing...
}
```